# Angular5 Bindings not working with function call in object [hidden]

Tags: html, angular, typescript, quill

I currently have the hidden attribute of one of my divs binded to a boolean in my typescript. But, when I am changing the value of the boolean in one of my function calls nested within an object the dom is not updating on the front end?

**typescript**

```js
hideSymbols = true;

bindings = {
    enter: {
      key: 13,
      handler: function() {
        console.log('enter pressed');
        this.hideSymbols = !this.hideSymbols;
        console.log(this.hideSymbols);
      }
    }
  };
```

**html**

```js
<div [hidden]="hideSymbols">
   <button id="equalsBtn" class="symbolBtn">=</button>
   <button id="impliesBtn" class="symbolBtn">=></button>
</div>
```

It works if I am not making the call in this handler but I need to in order for my ngx-quill instance to update how the enter key works. Essentially, **why is hideSymbols getting updated but on my web view the element does not disappear and reappear?**

Comment: `this.hideSymbols = !this.hideSymbols;` is probably executing in the wrong scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that:

```
handler: () => {...
```

...rather than use `function`. A function defined using `function` has its own `this`.

I'm not sure this is the whole problem without more context, but it's probably at least part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`this.hideSymbols = !this.hideSymbols;` is executing in the wrong scope.

This is what you have:

```js
var result1 = null;
var exhibitA = {
 execute: function(){
  this.result1 = "hello";
 }
};
exhibitA.execute();

console.log({ exhibitA, result1 });
```

This is what you want:

```js
var result2 = null;
var exhibitB = {
  execute: () => {
    this.result2 = "hello";
  }
};
exhibitB .execute();

console.log({ exhibitB, result2 });
```